# Create an array from MySQL query, average the values of that array, then round that average up

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Ok.  Here is the code I have so far...

```
mysql_query($userrating);
$userratingquery =  "SELECT rating FROM user_rating WHERE user_id=$sellerid";
$userrating = mysql_query($userratingquery) or die('SQL Error :: '.mysql_error());
$userrating = array();

while(($row =  mysql_fetch_assoc($userrating))) {
   $rating[] = $row['rating'];
}

if (!empty($userrating)) {
   $averagerating = array_sum($userratingary); 
   print_r($userratingary);
} else {
   echo '<img src="images/star.png" class="ratingstar" /><img src="images/star.png" class="ratingstar" /><img src="images/halfstar.png" class="ratingstar" />';
}
```

What I'm trying to do is create an array of the database values called "rating", average the values in that array, then I want to round those values up.  So, for instance, if the average of those values ends up being 3.7, then the average will then become 4.

From there I can apply the results to the code... I'm just having a lot of trouble with my array right now.  The error I'm getting right now is...

> Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL
>   result resource in

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
$userrating = mysql_query($userratingquery) or die('SQL Error :: '.mysql_error());
$userrating = array();
```

You are resetting the $userrating variable to an array so when you try to fetch a mysql row the $userrating mysql result is no longer valid.

Use a different variable name for your $userrating array or else another one for your mysql result.

Comment: You were right.  Thanks.  I also realized that in the while loop I didn't have the array variable set to the same variable I had designated in the first place.  That's also why the array wasn't being created.